# List within Dictionary on Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, search, extract

Okay so I am just starting out with Python and have encountered a list within a dictionary.

```
items_available = {
    "orders": [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 220, 330, 1000],
    "grapes": {"green": 3, "purple": 7, "white": 1},
    "litres_water": [1, 1.5, 2, 5, 10],
    "bread": 27
}
```

I need to somehow get all the information for the grapes part separately and I am confused about how to do this. eg. I previously founded the amount of grapes and the colour that the customer wants. I then need to check if it is available from this above given list.

I tried coding it like

```py
amount_of_grape_packs_needed = order_details[3] # amount the customer is requesting. Found previously. 
av_grapes = items_available.get('grapes')
max_available = amount_of_grape_packs_needed in av_grapesdesired_colour = order_details[2] in av_grapes
enough_packs = grape_amount_needed in max_available
```

??????? a mess. I know.
I also tried to extract the grapes as a list from the dictionary
and then work with just the list. But I made a mess of that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, please.
Thanks guys

(please excuse any formatting errors etc, this is my first time using stack overflow :) )

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? You can access dictionarys like this `items_available['grapes']` if that helps?

Comment: so say if the customer wants 2 packs of green grapes and the there is 3 packs of green grapes available, how do I check the customers values ONLY against the green grapes? Sorry if I am missing some understanding. Thank you for trying to help though.

Comment: Please add the output that you need

Answer (score 0):

To access the `keys()` and the `values()` of a dictionary, use `.items()`

```
items_available = {
    "orders": [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 220, 330, 1000],
    "grapes": {"green": 3, "purple": 7, "white": 1},
    "litres_water": [1, 1.5, 2, 5, 10],
    "bread": 27
}
for i,j in items_available['grapes'].items():
    print(i,j)
```

In list form:

```
[j for i in zip(items_available['grapes'].items()) for j in i]
```

Answer (score 0):

So if i understood this correctly what you want to do is

```
customer_grapes <= items_available['grapes']['green']
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, this is what you are trying to do.

User enters the required number of grapes (`n`) and the color of grapes (`color`).

The function `check()` checks whether the grapes ordered by  the user are present or not.

```
items_available = {
    "orders": [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 220, 330, 1000],
    "grapes": {"green": 3, "purple": 7, "white": 1},
    "litres_water": [1, 1.5, 2, 5, 10],
    "bread": 27
}


def check(color, n):
    data = items_available.get('grapes')
    if data[color] >= n:
        return f"Enough {color} grapes."
    else:
        return f"Not enough {color} grapes."
        
print(check('green',2))
print(check('white',4))
```

```
Enough green grapes.
Not enough white grapes.
```